# how to create for loop for symbolic link

Tags: linux, bash, loops, for-loop, ansible

i want for loop to create symbolic link for All the files under `/root/Desktop/match/jars/44a65820/*` to be under this path `/root/Desktop/match/jars/` as symbolic link without version 44a65820
for example

```
match@match:~/Desktop/match/jars# ls -ll
total 4
/root/Desktop/match/jars/match-five.jar -> /root/Desktop/match/jars/44a65820/match-five-44a65820.jar
/root/Desktop/match/jars/match-four.jar -> /root/Desktop/match/jars/44a65820/match-four-44a65820.jar
/root/Desktop/match/jars/match-one.jar ->  /root/Desktop/match/jars/44a65820/match-one-44a65820.jar
/root/Desktop/match/jars/match-three.jar -> /root/Desktop/match/jars/44a65820/match-three-44a65820.jar
/root/Desktop/match/jars/match-two.jar -> /root/Desktop/match/jars/44a65820/match-two-44a65820.jar
root/Desktop/match/jars/match-six.jar -> /root/Desktop/match/jars/44a65820/match-six-44a65820.jar
```

i don't know how to do?

Comment: i want to be like this resulte create  symbolic link without version

Comment: I would to a `ln` with no loop (`ln` can do the looping), followed by a `rename` to remove version number.

Comment: i want for loop because there are so much files so i want to do this and symbolic link without version

Comment: ln with wildcard or for with wildcard doesn't make any difference.

Comment: i modified i want like in the post this could you help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use parameter expansion to strip prefix and suffix.

```
for f in /root/Desktop/match/jars/44a65820/*; do
  link="${f%-44a65820.jar}.jar";
  ln -s "$f" "/root/Desktop/match/jars/${link##*/}";
done
```

Comment: i want for loop because there are so much files so i want to do this and symbolic link without version

Comment: working but not remove the version before .jar

Comment: i want match-five.jar match-one.jar , this working but get diffent resulte

Comment: @MuhammedOmar it works for me, so you have to explain how your results are "different". Without details it's impossible to help.

Comment: for f in /root/Desktop/match/jars/44a65820/*; do
  ln "$f" "/root/Desktop/match/jars/${f##*/}"
  # or: ln "$f" /root/Desktop/match/jars/
done

but not remove the version

Comment: Please, precise compatibles shells

Comment: @MuhammedOmar this was in an earlier version of the answer. Please see the latest version from 10 minutes ago.

Comment: its git this 44a65820.jar

Answer (score 0):

Given the simplified tree for testing

```bash
shell> tree /tmp/match
/tmp/match
└── jars
    └── 44a65820
        ├── one.jar
        ├── three.jar
        └── two.jar
```

In Ansible, declare the variable

```yaml
match_files: "{{ st.files|map(attribute='path')|list }}"
```

and [find](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/find_module.html#ansible-builtin-find-module-return-a-list-of-files-based-on-specific-criteria) the files

```yaml
    - find:
        path: /tmp/match
        file_type: file
        patterns: '*.jar'
        recurse: true
      register: st
```

gives

```yaml
match_files:
  - /tmp/match/jars/44a65820/two.jar
  - /tmp/match/jars/44a65820/one.jar
  - /tmp/match/jars/44a65820/three.jar
```

Create the [links](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/file_module.html#parameter-state) in the loop

```yaml
    - file:
        state: link
        src: "{{ item }}"
        dest: "{{ path }}/{{ file }}"
      loop: "{{ match_files }}"
      vars:
        arr: "{{ item.split('/') }}"
        path: "{{ arr[:-2]|join('/') }}"
        file: "{{ arr[-1] }}"
```

gives

```bash
shell> tree /tmp/match
/tmp/match
└── jars
    ├── 44a65820
    │   ├── one.jar
    │   ├── three.jar
    │   └── two.jar
    ├── one.jar -> /tmp/match/jars/44a65820/one.jar
    ├── three.jar -> /tmp/match/jars/44a65820/three.jar
    └── two.jar -> /tmp/match/jars/44a65820/two.jar
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    match_files: "{{ st.files|map(attribute='path')|list }}"

  tasks:

    - find:
        path: /tmp/match
        file_type: file
        patterns: '*.jar'
        recurse: true
      register: st
    - debug:
        var: match_files

    - file:
        state: link
        src: "{{ item }}"
        dest: "{{ path }}/{{ file }}"
      loop: "{{ match_files }}"
      vars:
        arr: "{{ item.split('/') }}"
        path: "{{ arr[:-2]|join('/') }}"
        file: "{{ arr[-1] }}"
```